# Minecraft Pocket Edition spawn bug

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was killed by a zombie in Minecraft PE 0.10.5, and instead of spawning me at my bed, a bug was continuously changing my position. Chunks appeared and disappeared continuously (visually). I reloaded the world and I died again. I re-spawned in a cave, deep underground.

How do I get my items back? (Please note that they are at the surface). I killed myself but I was spawned in the same place.